# ¿Por qué "Es usted muy amable" tiene una construcción gramatical de pregunta y tiene distinto sentido de "Usted es muy amable"?

Tags: gramática, preguntas

Un amigo me hizo notar el hecho curioso de que la frase

> Es usted muy amable

está formada gramaticalmente como una pregunta, a saber, es análoga a

> ¿Es usted el señor de la tele?

pero no pregunta nada. En cambio, se utiliza en el sentido de

> Usted es muy amable

pero esta variante suena demasiado directa y hasta algo acusatoria, en un contexto en el que importa ser lo más cordial posible. ¿Qué mecanismo gramatical está en juego aquí? ¿En qué otras ocasiones se usan formas análogas, y por qué se hace el cambio?

Comment: ¿Es usted muy amable? es una pregunta "Es usted muy amable" es una afirmación. La "construcción gramatical de pregunta" que mencionas en la pregunta no existe en español como si existe en inglés.

Answer (score 7):

El orden de palabras en español es mucho más flexible que en, por ejemplo, el inglés. El hecho de que el sujeto vaya después del verbo tiene poco que ver con que sea una oración interrogativa.

En cualquier caso, esa frase y otras similares han lexicalizado ya el orden de palabras y no hay mayor matiz ni nada especial. Son frases tan antiguas y tan usadas que sería casi una cuestión de gramática histórica ver por qué se usa ese orden y no otro.

Con el anterior párrafo quiero decir también que ni siquiera creo que proceda hablar de cambios en el orden de palabras "no marcado" para hablar de focalizar, etc. Simplemente esa frase se dice así porque de siempre se ha dicho así y, como digo, habría que hacer una investigación diacrónica para ver por qué, investigación que no creo que merezca la pena ni aun que sea fructífera.

Comment: Efectivamente.  En español, lo que más marca una oración como interrogativa es la entonación.

Answer (score 1):

Curiosamente, el único ejemplo de "usted" que presenta el diccionario de la RAE en la primera acepción o primer uso de la palabra muestra un caso de inversión:

*1. pron. person. 3.ª pers. m. y f. Forma que, en nominativo, en vocativo o precedida de preposición, designa a la persona a la que se dirige quien habla o escribe. U. generalmente como tratamiento de cortesía, respeto o distanciamiento. **Son ustedes** muy amables.*

Esto me hace pensar que "usted" es un pronombre particular en cuanto a su uso. A diferencia de otros pronombres que suelen omitirse, "usted" tiene mayor frecuencia de uso. Creo que, contrariamente a otros pronombres cuya omisión es más transparente (y en cuyo caso el sujeto tácito es inconfundible), como "usted" se conjuga en tercera persona su mención puede resultar necesaria para aclarar que la oración se refiere al interlocutor y no a un tercero.

Coincido con E.P. en que la oración sonaría demasiado directa o abrupta con "Usted" al principio, y que la posición de "usted" detrás del verbo suaviza ese efecto, al mismo tiempo que vuelve la oración más elegante, como en el ejemplo del DRAE transcripto al principio. En este punto, creo que la brevedad de "es" (o de "son") hace que mejore la cadencia con "usted" o "ustedes" pospuestos. Esa posición puede inclusive suavizar comentarios ofensivos como "Es usted bastante ignorante" o críticas como la que hice a quien juzgó mi respuesta con un voto negativo: "Es usted muy arbitrario".

Cabe observar que con "tú" no ocurre lo mismo: "Sos muy amable" / "Fuiste muy amable". Además, mi impresión es que, si bien es presente, el verbo "es" se refiere a actos de amabilidad recientes (y que muchas veces se usa en lugar del pretérito perfecto compuesto para no sonar tan excesivamente formal). Si usáramos el pretérito perfecto compuesto (una forma verbal que comparada con el presente es morfológicamente más extensa que el pronombre), "usted" se podría usar indistintamente antes o después del verbo:

- Usted ha sido muy amable. (formal)
- Ha sido usted muy amable. (aun más formal que la anterior)

Conclusión:

- *Es muy amable* puede ser ambigua en cuanto a quién está dirigida.
- *Usted es muy amable* es una simple afirmación.
- *Es usted muy amable* es, por su cadencia y elegancia, la forma más clara de dirigir un elogio o agradecimiento a la persona de "usted".

Comment: Al que me dio un voto negativo le digo, con todo respeto: Es usted muy arbitrario.

Comment: Acabo de eliminar el voto negativo. Lo puse cuando diste la respuesta original la cual era muy pobre a mi juicio y aceptaba el hecho de que el OP tenia razón al afirmar que la construcción hacia que la frase fuera interrogativa cuando en español la interrogación la hace la entonación y los símbolos ¿? y no la construcción. Si miras la historia de ediciones, de esa mala respuesta ya no queda prácticamente nada por lo que con la respuesta actual no tengo porque votar negativamente pero todos los cambios que le hiciste me confirman que ni siquiera tu considerabas buena tu respuesta original.

Comment: @DGaleano Gracias por tu honestidad. Es verdad que elaboré mejor algunos conceptos, pero creo que mantuve casi todas las ideas iniciales como la ambigüedad que implica no usar el "usted", el comportamiento de los demás pronombres, la similitud entre "es" y "ha sido" en ese contexto, la mayor elegancia del "usted" pospuesto. Si mi respuesta es ahora más clara, retiro el "Es usted muy arbitrario" y digo: Tu objeción ha resultado muy útil.